# Как на CSS сделать отсчет списка с нуля. Есть пример но он начинает считать с 1

Tags: html, css, html5

Вот мой код нумерованного списка, проблема в том что он начинает отсчет с единицы а нужно чтобы начинал с нуля. Как это реализовать на CSS? Возможности изменить HTML нет. Это я на Joomla опыты провожу.

```css
.lk_meny_active ul {
  counter-reset: li;
}
.lk_meny_active ul li a:before {
  border: 2px solid #666;
  color: #666;
  content: counter(li, decimal);
  counter-increment: li;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 24px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin-left: -50px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 33px;
}
```

```html
<div class="lk_meny_active">

  <ul class="menu" style="display: block;">
    <li class="current active" id="item-110">
      <a href="/index.php/obem-raboty"> <span> Объем работы</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="item-111">
      <a href="/index.php/rabota-v-gruppe-vk"> <span> Работа в группе ВК</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="item-112">
      <a href="/index.php/ceremonial"> <span> Церемониал</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="item-113">
      <a href="/index.php/razmeschenie-soobscheniya"> <span> Размещение сообщения</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="item-114">
      <a href="/index.php/naznachenie-znakomstva"> <span> Назначение знакомства</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="item-149">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" disabled="disabled" class="lk_meny_active_no"> <span> Знакомство</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="item-150">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" disabled="disabled" class="lk_meny_active_no"> <span> Выбор</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="item-151">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" disabled="disabled" class="lk_meny_active_no"> <span> Установление доверия</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="item-152">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" disabled="disabled" class="lk_meny_active_no"> <span> Выбор спонсора</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="item-153">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" disabled="disabled" class="lk_meny_active_no"> <span> Слово партнера</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="item-154">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" disabled="disabled" class="lk_meny_active_no"> <span> Запуск</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="item-155">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" disabled="disabled" class="lk_meny_active_no"> <span> Становимся спонсором</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="item-156">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" disabled="disabled" class="lk_meny_active_no"> <span> Установление доверия</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="item-157">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" disabled="disabled" class="lk_meny_active_no"> <span> Заключение партнерства</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

C нуля `counter-reset: li -1;`

[counter-reset](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/counter-reset)

```css
.lk_meny_active ul {
  counter-reset: li -1;
  
}
.lk_meny_active ul li a:before {
  border: 2px solid #666;
  color: #666;
  content: counter(li, decimal);
  counter-increment: li;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 24px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin-left: -50px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 33px;
}
```

```html
<div class="lk_meny_active">

  <ul class="menu" style="display: block;">
    <li class="current active" id="item-110">
      <a href="/index.php/obem-raboty"> <span> Объем работы</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="item-111">
      <a href="/index.php/rabota-v-gruppe-vk"> <span> Работа в группе ВК</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="item-112">
      <a href="/index.php/ceremonial"> <span> Церемониал</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="item-113">
      <a href="/index.php/razmeschenie-soobscheniya"> <span> Размещение сообщения</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="item-114">
      <a href="/index.php/naznachenie-znakomstva"> <span> Назначение знакомства</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="item-149">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" disabled="disabled" class="lk_meny_active_no"> <span> Знакомство</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="item-150">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" disabled="disabled" class="lk_meny_active_no"> <span> Выбор</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="item-151">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" disabled="disabled" class="lk_meny_active_no"> <span> Установление доверия</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="item-152">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" disabled="disabled" class="lk_meny_active_no"> <span> Выбор спонсора</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="item-153">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" disabled="disabled" class="lk_meny_active_no"> <span> Слово партнера</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="item-154">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" disabled="disabled" class="lk_meny_active_no"> <span> Запуск</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="item-155">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" disabled="disabled" class="lk_meny_active_no"> <span> Становимся спонсором</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="item-156">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" disabled="disabled" class="lk_meny_active_no"> <span> Установление доверия</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="item-157">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" disabled="disabled" class="lk_meny_active_no"> <span> Заключение партнерства</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Все, разобрался, делается так

```
.lk_meny_active ul {
    counter-reset: li -1;
}
```